# Is it possible to set a breakpoint in anonymous functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lambda, anonymous-function

I quickly want to determine whether/when a set of events are triggered. Therefore I quickly assigned empty lambda's to them.

```
_session.TopologyStarted += () => { };
```

When tracing through the code when the event is triggered, the debugger goes into the anonymous function, allowing to debug it's execution. However, when setting a breakpoint on this line of code, a breakpoint is set on the assignment of the anonymous function to the event.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint within the anonymous function?

Comment: You could make it multi-line, go to the `{` with the caret and then press `F9`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Put your cursor in the anonymous function (between the {}'s) and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: After that many years of using Visual Studio you'd think you'd know it all. :) I feel so stupid now, thanks!

Comment: When placing a breakpoint within empty brackets, you need to place the cursor right after the opening '{' for the breakpoint to be placed within the anonymous method.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work for me on a Lazy object - any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this by itself enough of a reason to use anonymous methods vs lambdas?

Comment: @dashnick Nope, you can do it as well using lambda expressions - working at least in my VS17RC ... Just place the cursor next to the lambda operator `=>` and hit F9.

Comment: Keep in mind that this [wont work on Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799704/) expressed as delegates

Comment: A note to anyone else that doesn't have f-keys (stupid macbook touchbar): you can also right-click > breakpoints > insert breakpoint.

Comment: can't get this to work, either.  The breakpoints are fine, but still don't get hit.

Comment: I am able to place a breakpoint within the anonymous function but the breakpoint is not getting hit during the debug. Any suggestions on how the breakpoint could be hit?